# How to formally calculate the rank of a matrix certain block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given the following block matrix: $$ C=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  I&A\\
\hline
  0&B
\end{array}
\right] $$
With $A,B,I,0 \in M_{n,n}(K)$ show that the rank of $C$ is $n+rk(B)$

To do this I've shown that the rank of $ \left[\!\!
\begin{array}{c|c}
  I&A\\
\end{array}\!\!
\right] $ is equal to $n$ since $I$ is a basis of $K^n$ and thus none of the columns of $A$ can be linearly independent with those of $I$.

Also I've argued that the rank of $ \left[\!\!
\begin{array}{c|c}
  0&B\\
\end{array}\!\!
\right] $ is just $\operatorname{rk}(B)$ because the columns of $0$ are exactly $0_{K^n}$ and thus cannot be linearly independent with the columns of $B$.

Of course both arguments are the same if we consider rows instead of columns.

To end my argument I would need to show that: $$\operatorname{rk}(C) = \operatorname{rk}(\left[\!\!
\begin{array}{c|c}
  I&A\\
\end{array}\!\!
\right])+\operatorname{rk}(\left[\!\!
\begin{array}{c|c}
  0&B\\
\end{array}
\!\!\right])=n+rk(B)$$
Which is quite clear but I'm not sure how to formalize it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is invariant under elementary row/column operations, that is adding or subtracting a row/column to or from another row/column.

Using elementary column operations you can kill off all of $A$ thanks to the columns of $I$, and these operations do not change $B$.

In the remaining block matrix, you see that the columns on the left are independent from the columns of the right, so that the ranks add up. [Hint on how to prove this properly: think of how you would prove properly that the $2\times 2$ identity matrix has rank $2$].

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes the argument even simpler, to state that the columns on the left are independent from those on the right is it okay to just say that they don't "share elements in the same rows"?

Comment: It depends on how precise you want your explanation to be. It is *roughly* correct, but a formal proof would take longer. I'll add a hint as to how to do that.